# delete file by looking at md5 checksum listed in lookup file

Tags: bash, unix

I need to delete files from a directory by looking at Md5 checksum values present in lookup file.

Lookup file values - md5lkp.txt

```
aac2050c8f3a0b6de33c6a0976a77c77  TEST_20190505060848.csv
c36c63d1b0dcf0a34a6285597ae67e93  TEST_20190505130157.csv
e72caf404c85d712971fa5b491204a58  TEST_20190506060803.csv
6c8dba8210a7df31aecd8b08c015919e  TEST_20190506130210.csv
782f1233c6e0a7763e41dd372834253f  TEST_20190507061001.csv
```

Files in dir - /home/usr1

```
TEST_20190505060848.csv
TEST_20190505060850.csv
TEST_20190506130210.csv
TEST_20190506130212.csv
```

From above list below 2 file should get deleted

```
TEST_20190505060848.csv
TEST_20190506130210.csv
```

Please advise.

Able to Solve this as below :

```
#!/bin/bash

lkpfile=$1

for i in *.csv
do
        md5check=`md5sum $i | cut -d' ' -f1`
        echo "current file $i md5 is $md5check"
        delfile=`grep -r $md5check $lkpfile`
        echo "delfile : $delfile"
        delfilename=`echo $delfile|awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`
        echo "deleting : $delfilename"
        rm $delfilename
done
```

Comment: It seems like this should be a very simple `while read md5 filename; do ...; done < md5lkp.txt` loop.

Comment: Why does the MD5 matter here? It looks like just a compare of file names. Or is MD5 just mentioned here since the file is MD5 command output?

Comment: need MD5 checksum value as same file can come again with different name but same content so need to delete file based on content and not the name.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. Able to solve this through grep

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t hashs < <(cut -d " " -f1 md5ljp.txt)
while read -r file; do
    sum=$(md5sum "$file")
    [[ ${hashs[*]} =~ ${sum%% *} ]] && rm "$file"
done < <(ls ./*.csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to achive this as below

```
#!/bin/bash

lkpfile=$1

for i in *.csv
do
        md5check=`md5sum $i | cut -d' ' -f1`
        echo "current file $i md5 is $md5check"
        delfile=`grep -r $md5check $lkpfile`
        echo "delfile : $delfile"
        delfilename=`echo $delfile|awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`
        echo "deleting : $delfilename"
        rm $delfilename
done
```